# Matlab connection to a remote server

Tags: matlab, ssh-tunnel

Is there a way to connect to a host through matlab using SSH? The way that can be done in vscode for example.
I have script and data in the remote machine but matlab license in my local machine. I would like to run the matlab scripts using matlab installed on my laptop.
Alternatively, I clone the scripts on my laptop run them while processing the data located in the remote machine.

Comment: Maybe you want to try to provide the data vie network share to the licensed machine, such as mounted network drive via NFS, Samba, etc.? This should work fine, when the data is of small size. Thus, you would only be limited by network speed.

Comment: If you don’t have a MATLAB installed on the remote machine, then you can’t run MATLAB on the remote machine. Any system you’d come up with that processes the data using the MATLAB installed on your laptop would involve transferring the script and the data to your laptop. There are many ways to do so, but why not just copy the files?

Comment: Alternatively, you can run a database server on the remote machine, and run local matlab as a [database cilent](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.html).

Comment: why not just copy the files? because it's more than 100 TB data!

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS

helps you mount a remote filesystem via ssh. So if you can login from your matlab laptop to the data pc via ssh , then sshfs is one step more. From there your data is a path on the matlab laptop.